# Core Data setting value of a NSDate type property

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsdate

Helo, I'm still newbie with Core Data and suddenly stuck in these simple code:

```
Purchased* newItem=[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Purchased" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[newItem setPurchasedDate:[NSDate date]];
[newItem setLastOpen:[NSDate date]];
if ([self.managedObjectContext save:&error])
{
   //do something if the save success
}
```

Well, from the code above I've Got an 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Purchased setPurchasedDate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance. As we can see the exception is pointing at

```
[newItem setPurchasedDate:[NSDate date]];
```

and that is right. When I try to debug this code step by step, the program just abort when this message is invoked.

I wonder why, cause there is no wrong in my model and my Purchased class, I've checked it hundred times. I have tried to change the location of setting value by overwrite -(void)awakeFromInsert() method and it's fire the same exception. Is anyone has a suggestion? thanks before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this:

Your managed object model's `Purchased` entity has an attribute of type `Date` that is called `purchasedDate`, and another one called `lastOpen`.

In your `Purchased.h` file you have

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *purchasedDate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *lastOpen;
```

In your `Purchased.m`file you have

```
@dynamic purchasedDate;
@dynamic lastOpen;
```

Make sure you `#import "Purchased.h"` in the file where you create the new instance.

Comment: shame on me, I wrote purchaseDate in my model hahaha. Thx for the answer.